# APK not being deleted from download folder

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, apk

I have set up a `Broadcast` that starts up when `Application` is installed with `startActivityForResult()`. The installation `Intent` is created here.

```
private static Intent getOpenDownloadedApkIntent(Context context, File file) {

    String name = getPackageNameForAPK(file.getPath(), context);
    if (name != null) {
        INSTALL_APK_INFO.put(name, file);
    }

    // The type of intent to use to open the downloaded apk changed in Android N (7.0)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".utils.DownloadedFileProvider",
                file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        intent.setData(path);
        return intent;
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        return intent;
    }
}

private static String getPackageNameForAPK(final String archiveFilePath, Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(archiveFilePath, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        return info.packageName;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now if it is Android 7 or higher, then the uninstall works, but if it is Android 6 or lower, then it just seems to delete the icon of the `APK` but not the `APK` itself.

Here is the code that should delete the `APK`:

```
private static BroadcastReceiver onInstallComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ApplicationInfo info = null;
            try {
                info = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(intent.getDataString().split(":")[1], PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
            }

            try {
                if (info != null) {
                    File file = INSTALL_APK_INFO.get(info.packageName);
                    if (file != null) {
                          file.delete();
                        INSTALL_APK_INFO.remove(info.packageName);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            }

        }
    };
```

I am guessing that is has something to do with the path, but at the same time it seems to delete the icon of the `APK`. By icon I mean that if i remove the `file.delete()` then the `APK` is with icon in downloads folder but if I run the `file.delete()` then the `APK` is without the icon.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean to say that app is getting installed but without launcher icon?

Comment: No app is getting installed as it should, but after the installation I want to delete the downloaded APK from the Download folder in the phone.  And when I am uninstalling it, it happens.